# Elasticsearch snapshot and store to IBM Object Store using `repository-s3`

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-s3, ibm-cloud, cloud-object-storage

I am trying to setup S3 Repository as a IBM Object Store.

I have configured, in the `elasticsearch.yml`

s3.client.default.endpoint: "s3.ap.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud"

And for the access key and secret:

`apikey` as Access Key ID

`resource_instance_id` as Secret access key

Error Log:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "repository_verification_exception",
        "reason": "[ibmdemo] path  is not accessible on master node"
      }
    ],
    "type": "repository_verification_exception",
    "reason": "[ibmdemo] path  is not accessible on master node",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "i_o_exception",
      "reason": "Unable to upload object [tests-L6P1BQdzSl2MXXX8O-Mm4w/master.dat] using a single upload",
      "caused_by": {
        "type": "amazon_s3_exception",
        "reason": "The AWS Access Key ID you provided does not exist in our records. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidAccessKeyId; Request ID: dfcf5efb-cf35-4d19-b4b6-17cXXXX03a54; S3 Extended Request ID: null)"
      }
    }
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

Let me know if there are other details needed.

Comment: I’m confused - you want to use S3 as a repo or IBM object storage?

Comment: Yes @ErmiyaEskandary, I want to use IBM Object Storage to do backup & resotre

Comment: What’s that got to do w S3?